# ¿Cómo sumar todos los valores numéricos de varios objetos dentro de un array? JS

Tags: javascript, array, objeto, jsx

muy buenas tardes ¿Cómo están?

Una consulta, estoy realizando una tarea y me surgió una duda ¿Es posible sumar todos los valores numéricos de varios objetos dentro de un array?

Por ejemplo tengo dos objetos:

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "nombre": "Camisas",
    "foto": "img",
    "tallas": 0,
    "tallam": 0,
    "tallal": 0,
    "tallaxl": 0
  },{
    "id": 4,
    "nombre": "Tapabocas",
    "foto": "img",
    "cantidad": 0
  },
```

Y quisiera mostrar la suma de las cantidades totales según el objeto, osea que cuando consulte el objeto 'camisas' me retorne el valor de la suma de todas las tallas, y cuando consulte el 'tapabocas' me retorne solamente la cantidad, osea la sumatoria de los valores numéricos menos el id, estos valores van reflejados en la siguiente tabla:

```
{queryInfo.data.map(inventoryDb => (
     <Tr key={inventoryDb.id}>
       <Td>{inventoryDb.id}</Td>
       <Td>{inventoryDb.foto}</Td>
       <Td>{inventoryDb.nombre}</Td>
       <Td isNumeric>{Acá me gustaría colocar el valor total de los valores  númericos dentro del objeto}</Td>
     </Tr>
```

¿Si es posible hacer esto?

Comment: .Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. este link puede ayudarte https://cosasreact.wordpress.com/
Lo ideal es compartir  lo que has intentado hacer. Para manejarte en el sitio  
 lee que tipos de preguntas debo evitar asi evitas que tu pregunta sea eliminada o reportada
preguntas constructivas son por ejemplo aquellas que inspiran respuestas que expliquen el porque y el como
e invitan a compartir experiencias respaldadas con hechos y referencias

Answer (score 2):

```
const array = [{
    "id": 1,
    "nombre": "Camisas",
    "foto": "img",
    "tallas": 1,
    "tallam": 3,
    "tallal": 2,
    "tallaxl": 1
},{
    "id": 4,
    "nombre": "Tapabocas",
    "foto": "img",
    "cantidad": 1
}]

function sumaValoresNumericos(obj){
    let suma = 0
    //Iteramos las claves del objeto
    for (const [clave, valor] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        //Si la clave no es 'id' y es de tipo numérico, sumamos el valor
        if (clave !== 'id' && (typeof valor === 'number')) suma += valor
    }
    return suma
}

console.log(array.map(item => sumaValoresNumericos(item)))
```

De todos modos este método no es el más confiable, porque si quieres agregar otras propiedades numéricas que no quieras sumar tendrás que agregar excepciones cada vez. Te recomendaria cambiar el esquema de los objetos a algo así si es posible:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "nombre": "Camisas",
    "foto": "img",
    "tallas": [
        {
            "nombre": "s",
            "cantidad": 1
        },
        {
            "nombre": "m",
            "cantidad": 3
        },
        {
            "nombre": "l",
            "cantidad": 2
        },
        {
            "nombre": "xl",
            "cantidad": 1
        },
    ]
}
```